# how to fix eclipse close automatically when starting in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse LUNA in that when I start debug mode the eclipse IDE will be closed. if any one can tell me why it happens and give the suggestion to solve it. And also tell me to start the template proposal because it won't start while entering ctrl+space,

Answer (score 0):

you can probably raise a issue in [Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/92/). If you dont have any specific requirements, you can probably go with Kepler as its more stable now.